# NGINX multiple sites but trying to serve static

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a domain eg: `domain.online` that I'm trying to add into my node server which runs using nginx.

Currently have 3 other sites running from them but they use `node.js` to run specific ports. So ports `3000` `9000`and `9001` are in use with `node` running them.

I've got a static html site in the directory `domain` which is situated `~/domain` but when I run the below and goto the domain in the browser Chrome shows the error `Page isn't working` and Dev Tools says `There are too many redirect`.

Can someone assist to allow me to get a static html site running without the need of node to tell which port to use.

```
# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS:
server {
        listen 8080;
        listen [::]:8080;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - proxy requests on to local Node.js app:
server {
        listen 443;
        root /domain;
        server_name domain.online;

        ssl on;
        # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.online/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.online/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        # Pass requests for / to localhost:9001:
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have the wrong port specified in your `proxy_pass` statement. 443 -> 8080 -> 443

Comment: @RichardSmith so you propose doing `proxy_pass http://localhost:443` ?

Comment: `proxy_pass` is used to reverse proxy to **another service** (e.g. node.js). If this server is only serving static content, remove the `proxy_` statements altogether.